# BASH ERROR when trying to get data from zimbra: value too great for base

Tags: bash, octal, zimbra

Although this error is quite common and explained almost everywhere on the web I've decided to ask a new question since I can't get a clue for this specific case.

I'm trying to get some data out of Zimbra Collaboration Suite and the only way I can do it is via bash.

Being my first time with bash I find it a bit hard to deal with.This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

all_account=`zmprov -l gaa`;
declare -i szquota
szquota=524288000
for account in ${all_account}
do
        mb_size=`zmmailbox -z -m ${account} gms`;
        set -i size;
declare -i quota
declare -i quota2
        for size in ${mb_size}
        do
                if [ $((10#$size)) -gt $((10#$szquota)) ] ; then
                        quota=`zmprov ga ${account} zimbraMailQuota`;
quota2="10#`zmprov ga ${account} zimbraMailQuota`";
                        echo "${account},${mb_size},$quota2\n";
                fi
        done
done
```

and this is the response:

```
line 12: 137,08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

I need to print all the accounts that have a quota of more than 500MB, and the output should be like this: account/quota/used quota.

Since `mb_size` is an array of values I can't figure out how I could convert its content to a decimal base as I did with the other values?
It probably is much simpler than my mind makes it look but I really can't get out of this trouble.
Kind regards

EDIT:

Thanks @Alfe!

I've modified the code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

all_account=`zmprov -l gaa`;

szquota=524288000
for account in ${all_account}
do
        mb_size=`zmmailbox -z -m ${account} gms`;
        declare -i quota
        declare -i quota2
        for sizeStr in ${mb_size}
        do
        if [ $size -gt $((10#$szquota)) ] ; then # <--- line 13
                        quota=`zmprov ga ${account} zimbraMailQuota`;
quota2="10#`zmprov ga ${account} zimbraMailQuota`";
                        echo "${account},${mb_size},$quota2\n";
                fi
        done
done
```

but it returns another error:
    line 13: [: -gt: unary operator expected

I've also tried to enclose the values inside the if clause between quotation marks but if I'm not wrong bash interprets the content of quotation marks as a string and gives back this:

```
line 13: [: : integer expression expected
```

I'm sure I'm getting closer to a solution but I'm still stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the variable `size` as integer with `set -i size`.  Later you try to assign a value which then is checked for being a valid integer, it isn't, then you get the error.  In your case, one of the values in `${mb_size}` is the string `08` which is then interpreted as a bad octal value.

I suggest you let the loop run over a different variable which is not declared as int (so the `for` statement won't posed a problem), then as first statement you assign the string value of the loop variable properly so that it does not get interpreted as octal:

```
for sizeStr in ${mv_size}
do
    size=$((10#$sizeStr))
    if [ $size -gt $((10#$szquota)) ]
    then
        …
```

You could of course also just remove the declaration of the variable as integer.  This probably would also solve the issue.

Comment: `set -i size` actually just sets `$1` equal to the string "size" while (I think) ignoring the `-i` flag.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that somewhere a `declare -i size` is in the actual code.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your answers!
I've edited the post with the changes I made according to your suggestions but I'm still stuck for some reasons.

By not declaring the variable as integer it returns 

     `line 13: [: -gt: unary operator expected` 

but if I try to enclose the variables between quotation marks it returns

    `line 13: [: : integer expression expected` 

I know I'm just a beginner but it's really driving me nuts

Comment: Debug by outputting what you've got in your variables.  Probably you've got sth like `137,08` in your variable.